# How to setup linear transformation to find the image

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $T:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ such that $$T(1,1,1) = (5,0,-1),\ T(0,-1,2)=(-3,5,-1),\ T(1,0,1)=(1,1,0)$$ Find the indicated image  $T(2,-1,1)$

The problem is that the text book only has a base case as an example:

```
T(1,0,0)=T(...)
T(0,1,0)=T(...)
T(0,0,1)=T(...)
```

And I can't find anything in any of the other chapters, that explain how to set up problem with the given values.

Comment: hint: (1,1,1), (0,-1,2), (1,0,1) forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find the image of $(2,-1,1)$ you should express it as a linear combination of $(1,1,1)$, $(0,-1,2)$ and $(1,0,1)$, *i.e.*
$$
\pmatrix{2\\1\\1} = \lambda \pmatrix{1\\1\\1} + \mu\pmatrix{0\\-1\\2} + \nu\pmatrix{1\\0\\1}.
$$
Note that this is just a linear system of 3 equations with 3 unknows, which has a unique solution, since $(1,1,1)$, $(0,-1,2)$ and $(1,0,1)$ form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$, they are linearly independent. After solving this system you can use the linearity of $T$ to compute the image.

Comment: So I look for the linear combination using the first part of each T. Do I take the unknowns that I find and multiply them to the value of each T to find the image?

Comment: Put the linear combination you got into $T$ and use the fact that $T$ is linear: $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$, $T(\lambda x)=\lambda\,T(x)$.